# Airport transit visa requirement for a Bangladeshi national flying from London to Toronto over Paris

Tags: visas, schengen, bangladeshi-citizens

I am a Bangladeshi national traveling from London to Toronto, Canada through CDG Paris, France by Air France. My transit time at CDG is 4h55m. Do I need an airport transit visa for this travel?

Comment: `ATV` = airport transit visa?

Comment: What sort of visa do you have for Canada?

Answer (score 1):

All the rules are explained in [Do I need a visa to transit (or layover) in the Schengen area?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-in-the-schengen-area)

Citizens of Bangladesh do require an airport transit visa (ATV) in France and elsewhere in the Schengen area but since you are traveling from the UK to Canada, it's safe to assume that you have either a residence permit or a visa for each of these countries and any one of these documents would exempt you from the ATV requirement. If that's indeed the case, you don't need a visa for this connection.